# How to connect VS to TFS Team Project from VSSDK

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

```
ITeamFoundationContextManager tfContextManager = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamFoundationContextManager)) as ITeamFoundationContextManager;
tfContextManager.SetContext(teamProjectCollection, projectUri);
```

This code does not work. plz

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Is tfContextManager coming back null? The call throws an exception...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you are asking here, but I have done some code which connects into TFS using the SDK which may be of help to you:

```
 private TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsServer = null;
 private VersionControlServer vcsServer = null;

 // This code is in a connection method
 tfsServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri (pServerName));
 tfsServer.EnsureAuthenticated();
vcsServer = (VersionControlServer)tfsServer.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
```

Then, you can extract the team project collection by using the following:

```
// attempt to extract a list of all projects

TeamProject[] projects = vcsServer.GetAllTeamProjects(true);

// add each one in turn to the list

foreach (TeamProject currentProject in projects)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to change the context within VS, not connect to an arbitrary server.